# Is it possible to work MVC 4 Project both with Visual Studio 2010 and 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

We are using a team project using TFS and it was created as ASP.NET MVC 3 project.

Some of team members have Visual Studio 2010 , some have Visual Studio 2013.

I upgraded project to MVC 4 to work with Visual Studio 2013 and opened solution with 2013. I migrated project to work with Visual Studio 2013 and made changes for the solution. I checked in the changes.

Now is it possible for team members having Visual Studio 2010, to work with this solution or they must install Visual Studio 2013 too?

Comment: The user will get maximum the warnings, you can ignore that. Problem will come only if the you have used some piece of code that is there in the new framework but not in the old ones. But still, since the framework is installed on the system, it should not give you the problem i guess...

Comment: Solution roundtripping works for most projects. Web Projects are one of those. It truly depends on what other kind of projects are part of your solution.

Comment: Turning your question on it's head... why don't all team members update to vs2013?